# Python, pygame - Loading image filename from string variable in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, pygame, filenames

I'm a beginning pygamer trying to upgrade a text game I wrote to a gui game.

```
animals = {dog: "Dog" 4 "Bone",
    cat: "Cat" 4 "Yarn",
    parrot: "Parrot" 2 "Bell"}

pet = animals[dog].split()

pet.append(pygame.image.load('//home/me/Desktop/Python/'+pet[0]+'.png')
```

If I were to input the above code and try to run it I get:

> pygame.error: Couldn't open //home/me/Desktop/Python/"Dog".png

How do I use a string variable from a list to load a file without getting quotes added to the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `"` in `pet[0]` with an empty string.

```
pet.append(pygame.image.load('//home/me/Desktop/Python/'+pet[0].replace('"', "")+'.png')
```

**Example:**

```
>>> animals = {'dog': '"Dog" 4 "Bone"',
    'cat': '"Cat" 4 "Yarn"',
    'parrot': '"Parrot" 2 "Bell"'}
>>> pet = animals['dog'].split()
>>> '//home/me/Desktop/Python/'+pet[0].replace('"', "")+'.png'
'//home/me/Desktop/Python/Dog.png'
```